# create two- or three-tape Turing machine to recognize the language $0^{2^n}$

Tags: turing-machines

I am creating a two-tape Turing machine to recognize the language $\{0^{2^n}|n\geq 0\}$. My idea is to put an input string, such as 0000, at the first tape, and use the second one to count the number of 0s in binary form (as a suggestion at [A two-tape deterministic Turing machine that recognizes an exponential string](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81878/a-two-tape-deterministic-turing-machine-that-recognizes-an-exponential-string)).  Every time Turing machine read a single 0, increase the counter (on the second tape) by 1. My difficulty is to write clearly the transition function, namely $\delta$, such as, I don't know how many states this Turing machine should have.

Comment: Are you supposed to give $\delta$ and the TM states *explicitly*? Usually, a precise description (in prose) suffices.

Comment: Well, *you* decide how many states the machine needs. Enough states to remember what it is supposed to be doing.